# My first JSF xhtml is showing blank page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, xhtml, tomcat7

I just downloaded Tomcat 7.0.53 and wrote my first JSF2.0 Hello World XHTML file (helloworld.xhtml) with Mojarra 2.0.3 implementation. 
My web.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>webroot</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My faces-config.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

</faces-config>
```

My webcontent/WEB-INF/lib folder contains the following jar files:

```
jsf-api.jar
jsf-impl.jar
jstl.jar
standard.jar
```

My helloworld.xhtml code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>Simple JSF Page</title>  
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:outputText>Hello World!</h:outputText>
</h:body>

</html>
```

When I run this using

```
http://localhost:8080/webroot/helloworld.faces
```

It shows a blank page. What is going wrong?

Comment: Does at least have a title in it?

Comment: Normally you'd map to *.xhtml in web.xml and call localhost:8080/.../helloworld.xhtml. "*.faces" is from JSF1 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of outputText is wrong

Change it to

```
<h:outputText  value="Hello World"></h:outputText>
```